# tkinter text button change size

Tags: python

My GUI app takes this text in first TextBox:

< C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\200-301-CCNA.pdf >
SHA-256: 68C3A9BC97E6303DAD3DB60028290B31DD77424A7C9A4F967FB531A47D17E4A2

If I  click on Prelucreaza Button, I will obtain in second TextBox this:

200-301-CCNA.pdf
SHA-256: 68C3A9BC97E6303DAD3DB60028290B31DD77424A7C9A4F967FB531A47D17E4A2

Now I'm trying to resize my TextBoxes, but if I change height or width in this line nothing happened (in GUI height will always be 40 and width 30).

```
text_multihasher = Text_Local(height=40, width=30, font=("Times New Roman", 12))
```

This is my code:

main.py

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from text_local import Text_Local


window = Tk()
window.title("Sha 256")
window.minsize(width=680, height=900)
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)
window.resizable(False, False)


def click_button():
    text_prelucrat.delete(1.0, END)

    multihash = text_multihasher.readlines()
    multihash_fara_pauza = []
    for hash in multihash:
        if hash != "":
            multihash_fara_pauza.append(hash)
    index_gasit = ""
    for index in range(0, len(multihash_fara_pauza)):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            denumire_fisier = multihash_fara_pauza[index]
            for i in range(0, len(denumire_fisier)):
                if denumire_fisier[i] == '\\':
                    index_gasit = i
            text_prelucrat.insert(END, f"{denumire_fisier[index_gasit+1:-2]}\n")

        if index % 2 == 1:
            text_prelucrat.insert(END, f"{multihash_fara_pauza[index][2:]}\n")
            text_prelucrat.insert(END, f"\n")


label_1 = Label(text="Introdu mai jos ce obtii in Multihasher:")
label_1.grid(column=0, row=0)

text_multihasher = Text_Local(height=40, width=30, font=("Times New Roman", 12))
text_multihasher.grid(column=0, row=1)

button = Button(text="Prelucreaza", command=click_button)
button.grid(column=0, row=2)

text_prelucrat = Text_Local(height=40, width=30, font=("Times New Roman", 12))
text_prelucrat.grid(column=0, row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

and text_local.py

```
from tkinter import *


class Text_Local(Text):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def readlines(self):
        new_list = []
        lungime = self.index(END)
        lungime_fara_ultimele_2 = lungime[:len(lungime)-2]
        for index in range(1, int(lungime_fara_ultimele_2)):
            element = self.get(f"{index}.0", f"{index}.0 lineend")
            new_list.append(element)
        return new_list
```

How can I resize my TextBoxes?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To resize a tkinter text box you change the height and width values just like you stated.  The following example will change the size of the text box when you change the height and width values.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sha 256")
root.geometry("680x900")
root.config(padx=20, pady=20)
root.resizable(False, False)

text_box = tk.Text(root, height=30, width=50, font="Times 12")
text_box.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think class Text_Local created this problem.
I used your code and you are right, I can change width and height.
When I copied class Text_Local in your code and use:

text_box = Text_Local(root, height=10, width=10, font="Times 12")

it creates a TextBox with different values for height and width than the values above.
I don't know where the new values come from.

Thank you!